# Get objects in date range when one of the dates is NULL in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails 5 app and at one part I want to get all object that are inside a given date range:

```
geo_locations.where(:created_at => @ride.first_at..@ride.last_at)
```

But in some cases first_at or last_at are NULL. If one of them is NULL I get the error:

```
ArgumentError (bad value for range)
```

In this case I would like to simply get an empty result. If first_at and last_at are NULL I do not get an error.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways of doing it:

```
geo_locations.where(:created_at => @ride.first_at..@ride.last_at) rescue []
```

OR

```
return [] unless @ride.first_at && @ride.last_at
geo_locations.where(:created_at => @ride.first_at..@ride.last_at)
```

**I would suggest second option as it reduces the risk of rescuing other unknown errors/exceptions**

Answer (score 0):

Not explicitly stated, but I assume you want an ActiveRecord::Relation as your return value still, and not an Array (as in [Md. Farhan Memon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746189/171183))? If so, you can use an ActiveRecord::NullRelation to achieve this by using [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#none](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none).

```
if @ride.first_at && @ride.last_at
  geo_locations.where(created_at: @ride.first_at..@ride.last_at)
else
  geo_locations.none
end
```

This way, you'll always get an empty result back after executing this query. Also, the query remains chainable as an ActiveRecord::Relation before executing it, regardless of which branch is taken in the conditional. Which is nice because it keeps the return type consistent!